# Limiting Amount of Posts in a Custom Post Type again

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I've been trying to limit the amount of posts a user can create in a specific custom post type, and I had some help from Bainternet by [checking out his plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/). I read over that and then came up with my own, but it doesn't seem to be working. I want to make my code much more lightweight than an entire new plugin so I am just adding it to mine, but what am I doing wrong here?

The name of my custom post type will be lets say.. `newpages`. And we'll pretend `$custom = 'Developer';` has been placed before the function.

```
function efpd_limit_posts(){
    global $pagenow,$custom;
    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='post-new.php?post_type=newpages'){
        $theposts = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'newpages'));
        if (count($theposts) >= '1'){
            wp_die('You have reached the maximum amount of 'newpages' you can create.');
}   }   }   
add_action('admin_head','efpd_limit_posts');
```

Comment: Now you left out 'author'=>$current_user->ID, from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array phrasing is wrong, cange

```
$count_posts = count(get_posts(array('author'=>$current_user->ID,'post_type','newpages')));
```

To

```
$count_posts = count(get_posts(array('author'=>$current_user->ID,'post_type' => 'newpages')));
```

Comment: Thanks again! I ought to just hire you to answer my questions! :)

Comment: @Bainternet: I meassured some "count"s and found them beeing extremly slow when not used outside a 'loop' (foreach, if, etc.) or directly on a function like `get_posts`. It's much faster if you do it like `$some_posts = get_posts... $count = count($some_posts)`

Comment: @Bainternet - I updated my code in my question, it doesn't seem to be working. Is there something else I'm forgetting here?

Comment: @Bainternet: You're welcome :)

Comment: @Kaiser: you left out the 'author'=>$current_user->ID, of the array

Comment: @Bainternet: I guess you're talking to @Jared?

Comment: @Kaiser: yep sorry its been a long day.

Comment: @Bainternet: ,)